# マイクで入力した音声をスピーカーで出力したい

Tags: python, python3

Python 3.x についての質問です。
マイクに一定以上の入力が一定時間無いと入力を中断し、
それまでに入力があった音声をスピーカーから出力するプログラムを考えております。
ですが、入力は受け付けるのですが、出力することが出来ません。
どなたかお知恵を貸していただけないでしょうか。

```
import pyaudio
import math
import struct
import time

Threshold = 50

SHORT_NORMALIZE = (1.0/32768.0)
CHUNK = 8192
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 16000
swidth = 2

TIMEOUT_LENGTH = 1

p=pyaudio.PyAudio()

def rms(frame):
    count = len(frame) / swidth
    format = "%dh" % (count)
    shorts = struct.unpack(format, frame)

    sum_squares = 0.0
    for sample in shorts:
        n = sample * SHORT_NORMALIZE
        sum_squares += n * n
    rms = math.pow(sum_squares / count, 0.5)

    return rms * 1000

stream=p.open(  format = pyaudio.paInt16,
        channels = 1,
        rate = RATE,
        frames_per_buffer = CHUNK,
        input = True,
        output = True) # inputとoutputを同時にTrueにする

while stream.is_active():
    current = time.time()
    end = time.time() + TIMEOUT_LENGTH

    while current <= end:
        data = stream.read(CHUNK)

        if rms(data) >= Threshold:
            end = time.time() + TIMEOUT_LENGTH
            print(rms(data))

        current = time.time()
        # output = stream.write(data) # ここでならスピーカーから音声が出力される(ここには書きたくない)
        
    output = stream.write(data) # ここでスピーカーから音声を出力したい

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()

print("Stop Streaming")
```

Comment: このままリモート会議用ヘッドセットのように1つで入出力両方をこなせるデバイスを使うか、ストリーム/チャンネルを入力用と出力用の2つに分けてみるとかしてはどうでしょう？

Comment: 一時的に音声を録音して、入力が途切れたら後から再生する…というイメージで合っていますか？

Comment: >kunifさん
私はストリームに関する理解が不足していて難しそうです。ですが、その方向も調べてみます！

>cubickさん
そうです！その通りです！Pythonでそれが実現出来ればどのような形でも構いません。(私の提示したソースコードと全く違っていても構いません。)

Comment: まあ最初の文の方が主眼で、ヘッドセットをメインのデバイスとして使ったら質問のソースコードを何も変更せずに動作しました。だからマイクとスピーカーでは入力デバイス/チャンネルと出力デバイス/チャンネルが分かれているかもしれないと思って2つ目の文を書いています。例えばこんな記事を参考にデバイス/チャンネルとin/outの属性を調べてみてはどうでしょう？ [How to select a specific input device with PyAudio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36894315/9014308)

Comment: ソースコードを以下のように修正したら想定通りの動きをしました。ありがとうございました。while stream.is_active():  
    current = time.time()  
    end = time.time() + TIMEOUT_LENGTH  
    save_data = [] # 入力データを貯めるため  

    while current <= end:  
        data = stream.read(CHUNK)  
        save_data.append(data) # データを貯める  

        if rms(data) >= Threshold:  
            end = time.time() + TIMEOUT_LENGTH  
            print(rms(data))  

        current = time.time()  

    # 貯めたデータを出力する  
    for data in save_data:  
        output = stream.write(data)

Comment: コメントでは書式が指定できず見難いので、解決されたなら自己回答として下の回答の方に記述してみてください。

Answer (score 0):

以下はコメント欄に書かれた結果をコミュニティWiki形式の回答としたものです。

---

ソースコードを以下のように修正したら想定通りの動きをしました。

```
while stream.is_active():
    current = time.time()
    end = time.time() + TIMEOUT_LENGTH

    save_data = [] # 入力データを貯めるため
    while current <= end:
        data = stream.read(CHUNK)
        save_data.append(data) # データを貯める

        if rms(data) >= Threshold:
            end = time.time() + TIMEOUT_LENGTH
            print(rms(data))

        current = time.time()

    # 貯めたデータを出力する
    for data in save_data:
        output = stream.write(data)
```